# Are you "making up" a story (to try to deceive me)?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> Are you making up a story (to try to deceive me)?
>   Are you fabricating a story (to try to deceive me)?

Which word is most commonly used to indicate that a kid tells a false story as if it were true to an adult?

Comment: *Are you making that up?* is quite common, in my opinion. Also consider: *Did you just make that up?*

Comment: Also, (to try to *fool* me), especially children might say this.

Comment: Are you asking for something that someone says to the child after hearing the story (probably a question, like the examples in your post and the previous comments), or a simple description of what the child did (for example, *the child was trying to fool me*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Make up' is a phrasal verb. Most phrasal verbs have a single-word equivalent which is often longer and more formal. Talking to a child, you would probably use 'make up'. 
And as other commenters have mentioned, 'fool' is more likely than 'deceive'. (There are also other possible words, such as 'trick'). Usually, the shorter words are less formal, and the longer words are more formal.